# Rails : can't write unknown attribute `url'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am new to ruby on rails,and I am learning by creating a blog. I am not able to save to my blogs table and I get this error "can't write unknown attribute url"

**Blogs migration:** db/migrate/

```
class CreateBlogs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :blogs do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.string :slug
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Blogs Model:** /app/models/blogs.rb

```
class Blogs < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_url :title
  def to_param
    url
  end
  validates :title, presence:true
end
```

**Blogs Controller:** /app/controllers/blogs_controller.rb

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_login

  def new
    @blogs = Blogs.new
  end

  def show
    @blogs = Blogs.find_by_url(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @blogs = Blogs.new(blogs_params)
    if @blogs.save

      flash[:success] = "Your Blog has been created."

      redirect_to home_path

    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def blogs_params
    params.require(:blogs).permit(:title,:description)
  end


  private

  def require_login
    unless signed_in?
      flash[:error] = "You must be logged in to create a new Blog"
      redirect_to signin_path
    end
  end
end
```

Blogs Form:/app/views/blogs/new.html.erb

> Blockquote

```
<%= form_for @blogs, url: blogs_path do |f| %><br/>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages_blogs' %><br/>
<%= f.label :title %><br/>
<%= f.text_field :title %><br/>
<%= f.label :description %><br/>
<%= f.text_area :description %><br/>
<%= f.submit "Submit Blog", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %><br/>
<% end %><br/>
```

and I have also added "resources :blogs" to my routes.rb file.

I get this error in controller at

> if @blogs.save

Comment: Please fix your code. Delete that mess, and paste in a fresh copy, then select it all and hit the `{}` button to format it.

Comment: I reformatted it all, however the person who looked at my edits decided to reject them.  So its a mess again :(

Comment: I reformatted it.Sorry i am new to stackoverflow :)

Comment: Take a look at Markdown ~ Thats the syntax language that StackOverflow (and many others like GitHub) use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error states exactly what your issue is: `"can't write unknown attribute url"` Implies that the `url` variable you are trying to access in `def to_params` of your `Blogs` model to which is unknown as you wish to store this in `slug`.  The `acts_as_url` method is added and used by the [stringex gem](https://github.com/rsl/stringex) and because you aren't getting an error regarding an unknown method acts_as_url, the gem must successfully be installed, just *misconfigured*.

Looking further into the documentation for the gem, the gem sets the value of the url to a db column that should already exists in your model.  From your database schema, the url should use the column `slug` and not `url` (the default of stringex).  Changing your Blogs Class to the following *should* fix the issue:

```
class Blogs < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_url :title, url_attribute: :slug
  def to_param
    slug
  end
  validates :title, presence:true
end
```